# Installing Firebase to my Xcode project resulted into generating 4 warnings I cannot seem to find a fix for

Tags: xcode, firebase, swiftui, cocoapods

I tried looking through many stackOverFlow posts in order to find the solution to this problem but I cant seem to find any, can someone explain why this error is generating and possible a fix to it? Thank you in advance!

Im working on this application in a course, and in this section of the module, I'm installing Firebase to the application in order to let a user register and login to the app, after the installing the the Firebase pods I ran into 10 errors, was able to fix 6 of them by doing some research but I was left with 4 errors that reflect back to the same line "typedef struct" in 3 different files, internal.h, credentials.h and ssl_security_connector.h.

/Users/adham/Desktop/Projects/Flash-Chat-iOS13/Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/lib/security/credentials/credentials.h:205:15: Anonymous non-C-compatible type given name for linkage purposes by typedef declaration; add a tag name here

and it is highlighting this block of code

```
typedef struct {
  grpc_mdelem* md = nullptr;
  size_t size = 0;
} grpc_credentials_mdelem_array;
```

This error in gRPC-Core was also found in gRPC-C++ Group, it was labeled as "Semantic issue"

Im new to stackOverFlow please don't judge my posts, only getting started!

Comment: This is a new issue with Xcode 13 and one of Firestore's dependencies. File an issue at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues and the fix will be prioritized.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do you mean warnings or errors ? By default those messages will be warnings.

You can switch off warnings from pod frameworks by adding

`inhibit_all_warnings!`

To your Podfile and calling `pod install`

If you want to fix the warning change the structure of that declaration to.

```
struct grpc_credentials_mdelem_array {
  grpc_mdelem* md = nullptr;
  size_t size = 0;
};
```

Lose the `typedef` and the name comes to the front after `struct`

But to make it sticky through pod installs you need to fork the repos and point to your own fork in the Podfile.

Most of the time unless it’s stopping your work you can ignore pod warnings.

Comment: My apologize I actually meant warnings every time I said errors, I personally wanted to fix the warnings rather than just turning them off, but I did the following to every line of code that was throwing the same warning, and man that work like a charm! Thank you so much Warren!

Comment: You’re welcome, and do file a bug with the url PaulB mentioned above. That way it’ll get fixed at the source.

Comment: I had a similar issue after updating Xcode to 13 and all of a sudden I ended up with 60+ warnings related to gRPC.  I followed the advice above in relating to fixing the struct commands and it worked a treat.  Thank You Warren.

Comment: Thank you! I did the second change with losing the typedef from the struct

Comment: This same fix, also works for internal.h and ssl_security_connector.h files.  When you fix ONE of the warnings, all the rest in that same file will go away.  So what looks like > 50 warnings, is really 3 fixes in total, and the fix is same methodology @WarrenBurton outlines above.  cut-paste the struct name from that last line, up after Struct, and delete the typeDef word.